# ComboBox's SelectionChanged is fired when DataGrid elements are grouped

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox, grouping, selectionchanged

in my DataGrid i have a ComboBox in a DataGridTemplateColumn and i want to react on a SelectionChanged-event. My XAML:

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged" 
    SelectionMode="Single" Name="dataGrid1" ...>
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander Name="exp" IsExpanded="True">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedValue, 
                                            ElementName=groupCB}"/>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <Expander.Content>
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </Expander.Content>
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="status" ...>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StatusL, RelativeSource={
                        RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={
                        x:Type Window}}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Status}" 
                        Name="statusCB" SelectionChanged="StatusCB_SelectionChanged" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And the SelectionChanged-Method of the ComboBox:

```cs
private void StatusCB_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```

The DataGrids DataContext is a CollectionView of a DataTable. To group the DataGrid rows i use this code:

```cs
DataTable _record_data = new DataTable("records");
CollectionView _records_view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_record_data);
dataGrid1.DataContext = _records_view;

PropertyGroupDescription _group_description = new PropertyGroupDescription(groupCB.SelectedValue.ToString()); // groupCB is another ComboBox

_records_view.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
_records_view.GroupDescriptions.Add(_group_description);
```

When a new row is inserted into the DataGrid the SelectionChanged-method for the ComboBox of that row is called. When i change the selected item of the rows ComboBox i want to regroup the DataGrid. But adding a new GroupDescription in the regroup-method calls the SelectionChanged method of each row. This ends in an infinit loop.

I hope i could explain my problem.

Thanks alot for any help

Comment: try e.Handled=True..in StatusCB_SelectionChanged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your event handler to handle `DropDownClosed` instead of `SelectionChanged`

```
<ComboBox DropDownClosed="ComboBox_DropDownClosed" ... />

private void ComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

This will only execute when the user closes the drop down popup. Note that `DropDownClosed` will execute if they select the same item or index, unlike `SelectionChanged` which only executes upon "change"